# javascript array_pop

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

Is there a nifty trick for PHP's `array_pop()` in Javascript?

In lieu of any niftiness, I will accept elegance and/or brevity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var foo = [1,2,3];
foo.pop();
```

Answer (score 2):

Javascript has a pop function: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_pop.asp

Comment: While that page covers the salient points, it does so with bad examples and masses of advertising. W3Schools is very low quality through out (often having massive security problems with its tutorials) so please don't link to it. MDC is usually a much better JS reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop

Comment: Also, to complete the airhead moment, I was looking for `shift()`.  :S Time for bed I guess.